# Configuration of jBPM in Jhipster

Tags: java, jhipster, jbpm

I am new in Jhipster.I want to use both jBPM and Jhipster.I am not able to call even simple jbpm process using Jhipster.

Firstly I tried to run simple jbpm process through rest API call it gives me an error **H2 datasource not defined**.

At second time I tried to run simple jbpm process where I used persistance.xml for jBPM database connectivity then I got an error as **No Persistence provider for EntityManager named org.concreatepage**

Please help me to come out of it.

Thanks.

Comment: I have updated my question could you please remove on hold tag.

Answer (score 3):

We implemented it, for one of my customer, so I can't share any code. But it is pretty simple.

All steps you can follow:

- First, generate a JHipster project with simple configuration (no MongoDB, Cassandra, etc)
- Look at the code at this repository  https://github.com/mswiderski/jbpm-examples/tree/master/spring-boot-jbpm
- Add dependencies, config xml files, etc.

Alternative solution would be to use Activi:

- here the ticket: https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/6454
- here the module: https://github.com/Activiti/generator-jhipster-activiti

Comment: But how do you configured persistance.xml in liquibase ?

Comment: We didn't use liquibase for that. You can let hibernate to do the job: https://github.com/mswiderski/jbpm-examples/blob/master/spring-boot-jbpm/src/main/resources/META-INF/jbpm-persistence.xml#L67

Or, you can use a SQL script to create the database in prod.

Comment: Thank you for reply. How do you remove liquibase from Jhipster ?

Comment: In my project, we still use liquibase to create other tables, so we don't remove it. We simply don't use liquibase to create the tables which are in persistence.xml file.
To delete liquibase, delete dependencies in pom.xml, then clean application.yml properties and clean Java code which import liquibase librairies.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have added the persistence.xml on the classpath but not able to get how can we configure it with the Liquibase. Is there need to  configure the persistence unit with the liquibase? if yes then How can we.

Comment: @Smurfy you can find some documentation here https://www.jhipster.tech/development/#using-a-database. If I'm not wrong in the docs you can find how to disable liquibase. I wouldn't do it anyway, why don't you keep it for jhipster entities, and just ignore them?